# Convert list of lists to dataframe, where each list represents a row, preserving types

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of lists, where each sub list represents a row.  I would like to convert this into a data frame, preserving the types of all columns.  This feels like it should be quite straightforward, but I keep running into problems.

Is my second solution the best approach?

```
l1 <- list(id="a", date=as.Date("2017-01-01"), value=10)
l2 <- list(id="b", date=as.Date("2017-01-02"), value=12)
list_of_lists <- list(l1,l2)

# Does not work - dates are converted to integers
do.call(rbind.data.frame, list_of_lists)

# Does work, but have to explicitly pass stringsAsFactors, 
# and seems inefficient
list_of_dfs <- lapply(list_of_lists, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
do.call(rbind, list_of_dfs)
```

Comment: You could just convert the integers back to dates in a one call. Something like `res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, list_of_lists) ; res$date <- as.Date(res$date, origin = "1970-01-01")`

Comment: Thanks - good idea.  Do you know why it doesn't preserve the date type in the first place?

Comment: It's documented under `?rbind.data.frame`: "*Any classes the inputs might have are discarded...*" So the underlying storage mode of a Date class in numeric (check out `storage.mode(as.Date(Sys.Date()))`) so when the class is stripped, it becomes a number (which could be converted back to a date of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something tidy,

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(list_of_lists)
# A tibble: 2 × 3
#     id       date     value
#    <chr>     <date>   <dbl>
#1     a    2017-01-01    10
#2     b    2017-01-02    12
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list_of_lists)
#   id       date value
#1:  a 2017-01-01    10
#2:  b 2017-01-02    12
```